# Passing object references needlessly through a middleman

Tags: oop

I often find myself needing reference to an object that is several objects away, or so it seems. The options I see are passing a reference through a middle-man or just making something available statically. I understand the danger of global scope, but passing a reference through an object that *does nothing* with it feels ridiculous. I'm okay with a little bit passing around, I suppose. I suspect there's a line to be drawn somewhere.

Does anyone have insight on where to draw this line?

Or a good way to deal with the problem of distributing references amongst dependent objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (with moderation and good taste, not dogmatically).  If you're coding `a.b.c.d.e`, something IS wrong -- you've nailed forevermore the implementation of `a` to have a `b` which has a `c` which... EEP!-)  One or at the most two dots is the maximum you should be using.  But the alternative is NOT to plump things into globals (and ensure thread-unsafe, buggy, hard-to-maintain code!), it is to have each object "surface" those characteristics it is designed to maintain as part of its interface to clients going forward, instead of just letting poor clients go through such undending chains of nested refs!

Comment: +1: globals aren't a solution -- they're a different (often worse) problem.

Answer (score 1):

This smells of an abstraction that may need some improvement. You seem to be violating the [Law of Demeter.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Answer (score 1):

In some cases a global isn't too bad.

Consider, you're probably programming against an operating system's API. That's full of globals, you can probably access a file or the registry, write to the console. Look up a window handle. You can do loads of stuff to access state that is global across the whole computer, or even across the internet... and you don't have to pass a single reference to your class to access it. All this stuff is global if you access the OS's API.

So, when you consider the number of global things that often exist, a global in your own program probably isn't as bad as many people try and make out and scream about.

However, if you want to have very nice OO code that is all unit testable, I suppose you should be writing wrapper classes around any access to globals whether they come from the OS, or are declared yourself to encapsulate them. This means you class that uses this global state can get references to the wrappers, and they could be replaced with fakes.

Hmm, anyway. I'm not quite sure what advice I'm trying to give here, other than say, structuring code is all a balance! And, how to do it for your particular problem depends on your preferences, preferences of people who will use the code, how you're feeling on the day on the academic to pragmatic scale, how big the code base is, how safety critical the system is and how far off the deadline for completion is.

Comment: An interesting insight of yours:
"...wrapper classes around any access to globals..."

Wrapping something in its own class is a good way of 'shelving' it in a container that can later be re-purposed. The more of these temporary, non-destructive solutions at one's disposal, the easier it will be to gain momentum while coding/designing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is revealing something about your classes. Maybe the responsibilities could be improved ? Maybe moving some code would solve problems ?

---

> Tell, don't ask.

That's how it was explained to me. There is a natural tendency to call classes to obtain some data. Taken too far, asking too much, typically leads to heavy "getter sequences". But there is another way. I must admit it is not easy to find, but improves gradually in a specific code and in the coder's habits.

Class A wants to perform a calculation, and asks B's data. Sometimes, it is appropriate that A tells B to do the job, possibly passing some parameters. This could replace B's "getName()", used by A to check the validity of the name, by an "isValid()" method on B.
"Asking" has been replaced by "telling" (calling a method that executes the computation).

For me, **this is the question I ask myself when I find too many getter calls**. Gradually, the methods encounter their place in the correct object, and everything gets a bit simpler, I have less getters and less call to them. I have less code, and it provides more semantic, a better alignment with the functional requirement.

---

> Move the data around

There are other cases where I move some data. For example, if a field moves two objects up, the length of the "getter chain" is reduced by two.

I believe nobody can find the correct model at first.
I first think about it (using hand-written diagrams is quick and a big help), then code it, then think again facing the real thing... Then I code the rest, and any smells I feel in the code, I think again...

---

> Split and merge objects

If a method on A needs data from C, with B as a middle man, I can try if A and C would have some in common. Possibly, A or a part of A could become C (possible splitting of A, merging of A and C) ...

---

However, there are cases where I keep the getters of course.
But it's less likely a long chain will be created.
**A long chain will probably get broken by one of the techniques above**.

Answer (score 0):

I have three patterns for this:

1. Pass the necessary reference to the object's constructor -- the reference can then be stored as a data member of the object, and doesn't need to be passed again; this implies that the object's factory has the necessary reference. For example, when I'm creating a DOM, I pass the element name to the DOM node when I construct the DOM node.
2. Let things remember their parent, and get references to properties via their parent; this implies that the parent or ancestor has the necessary property. For example, when I'm creating a DOM, there are various things which are stored as properties of the top-level DomDocument ancestor, and its child nodes can access those properties via the reference which each one has to its parent.
3. Put all the different things which are passed around as references into a single class, and then pass around just that one class instance as the only thing that's passed around. For example, there are many properties required to render a DOM (e.g. the GDI graphics handle, the viewport coordinates, callback events, etc.) ... I put all of these things into a single 'Context' instance which is passed as the only parameter to the methods of the DOM nodes to be rendered, and each method can get whichever properties it needs out of that context parameter.